# regarding PECS java generics

Tags: java, generics

Reading Java Essentials, 2nd edition, there's a rule called PECS for type safety in method parameters.  If it produces you extend, consumes you use super.  Sorry if I defined it wrong as I don't get it.

Can anyone shed light on what Joshua Bloch is referring to as the producer/consumer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [pdf](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2008/pdf/TS-6623.pdf) which has a series of slides on this (search for PECS):

**Generic types are invariant**

• That is, `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`
• Good for compile-time type safety, but inflexible

**Bounded wildcard types provide additional API flexibilty**

• `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Object>`
• `List<Object>` is a subtype of `List<? super String>`

so

*PECS* — *Producer extends, Consumer super*

• use `Foo<? extends T>` for a `T` producer
• use `Foo<? super T>` for a `T` consumer

only applies to input parameters (Don’t use wildcard types as return types).

Suppose you want to add bulk methods to Stack:

```
void pushAll(Collection<? extends E> src);
//src is an E producer

void popAll(Collection<? super E> dst);
// dst is an E consumer
```

Comment: @Jeroen Thx for formatting. I simply cut and pasted the reference - it looks unaltered

Comment: Then why public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj) uses super although it is consuming it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_fill.htm

Comment: "Don’t use wildcard types as return types." Unless you need a method similar to `getClass()` (which actually goes beyond just having a wildcard return type as in its declaration, `Class<?>` [which is equivalent to `Class<? extends Object>`]; it returns a `Class<? extends [whatever class getClass() was called in]>`). ...I suppose that doesn't really apply to using generics with collections, though.

Comment: The link does not map to the pdf :(

Answer (score 3):

When a method reads/iterates over elements in a collection then it is a consumer, when it ads to a collections then it is a producer.